# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)^k}{n^a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the above series with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a>1$, how can I prove its convergence? The ratio test doesn't provide additional information, and I don't know how to prove an antiderivative for the integral test. Other conventional series convergence tests do not seem applicable.

Comment: Try the squeeze theorem or telescoping.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac {(\ln n)^{k}} {n^{(a-1)/2}}=\frac {(\ln n)^{k}} {n^{a}} n^{(a+1)/2}\to 0$ since $\frac {\ln n} {n^{t}}\to 0$ for any $t>0$. Now compare the given series with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{(1+a)/2}}$